# How to group a Dictionary by DateTime and average results using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this data set.

`var results = new Dictionary<DateTime, Result>()`

The `Result` class looks like this:

```
public class Result
{
   public decimal Temperature { get; set }
   public decimal DayTime { get; set; }
}
```

My data set will look something like this:

```
Dictionary Key     Dictionary Value (Result class)
--------------     -------------------------------
01/01/2020 09:00   { Temperature: +9, DayTime: true }
01/01/2020 18:00   { Temperature: +5, DayTime: false}
01/02/2020 09:00   { Temperature: +8, DayTime: true }
01/02/2020 18:00   { Temperature: +3, DayTime: false }
```

My goal is to average monthly day and night temperatures which would give something like this:

```
01/2020 - DayTime   Avg. Temp +9
01/2020 - NightTime Avg. Temp +5
02/2020 - DayTime   Avg. Temp +8
02/2020 - NightTime Avg. Temp + 3
```

Note there will be many more data points as I will have data for every hour of every day in a given year.

I've started using the `GroupBy()` method on the `Dictionary` type but I can't work out how to drill into each result to separate by day/night and average the temperatures.

Is this possible to do with Linq or should I just loop over the results, use linq to extract monthly data and average over the values? I could get a distinct month list and then loop over that selecting day/night values and performing an average?

If there is a more succinct way to do this I would be happy to learn.

Comment: Have you tried the `OrderBy` method?

Comment: @RamonDias : How does OrderBy solve the Averaging?

Comment: Shouldn't the `DayTime` property of `Result` be `bool`?

Answer (score 0):

This is challenging to do in one linq.  You want two uneven groupings of 9 hours and 15 hours.  So you group by days and then subtract 9 hours to start a 9:00AM and then test if the offset is less than 9 hours (9:00 AM to 6:00 PM) or greater.  I had to make temperature accept a null because a range could have no temperatures.
See solution below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSpan SIX_PM = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0); // Time from midnight to 6PM;

            List<Result> input = new List<Result>() {
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 2:00"), Temperature = 2},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 4:00"), Temperature = 3},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 6:00"), Temperature = 4},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 8:00"), Temperature = 5},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 10:00"), Temperature = 6},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 12:00"), Temperature = 7},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 14:00"), Temperature = 8},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 16:00"), Temperature = 9},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 18:00"), Temperature = 10},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 20:00"), Temperature = 11},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/28/20 22:00"), Temperature = 12},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 0:00"), Temperature = 13},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 2:00"), Temperature = 14},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 4:00"), Temperature = 15},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 6:00"), Temperature = 16},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 8:00"), Temperature = 17},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 10:00"), Temperature = 18},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 12:00"), Temperature = 19},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 14:00"), Temperature = 20},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 16:00"), Temperature = 21},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 18:00"), Temperature = 22},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 20:00"), Temperature = 23},
                new Result() { DayTime = DateTime.Parse("10/29/20 22:00"), Temperature = 24}
            };




            Dictionary<DateTime, Result> results = input.GroupBy(x => x.DayTime, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            var data = results.GroupBy(x => x.Key.AddHours(-9).Date)
                .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                .Select(y => (y == 0) 
                    ? new
                        {
                            Date = x.Key.AddHours(9).ToString(),
                            AverageTemperature = x.Where(z => z.Key - x.Key  < SIX_PM)
                                .Average(z => z.Value.Temperature),
                            DayTime = "DayTime"
                        }
                    : new
                        {
                            Date = x.Key.AddHours(18).ToString(),
                            AverageTemperature = x.Where(z => z.Key - x.Key  >= SIX_PM)
                                .Average(z => z.Value.Temperature),
                            DayTime = "NightTime"
                        }
            ))
            .Where(x => x.AverageTemperature != null)
            .ToList();


    
        }
        public class Result
        {
            public decimal? Temperature { get; set; }
            public DateTime DayTime { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to nest your `GroupBy`s to handle each grouping: one for date then one for `DayTime`. I used `SelectMany` to flatten the sub-groupings but you could keep them instead.

```
var ans = results.GroupBy(dr => dr.Key.Date, dr => dr.Value)
                 .SelectMany(rg => rg.GroupBy(r => r.DayTime, r => r.Temperature).Select(tg => new { Date = rg.Key, DayTime = tg.Key, AvgTemp = tg.Average() }))
                 .ToList();
```